# Facebook SDK 3: how to sort friends list alphabetically (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, sorting, facebook-graph-api

Using the `Facebook SDK 3`, I am getting the list of `GraphUser` of my friends list, but when I put it into a custom `ListView` everyone is out of order.

Does the SDK have a way to sort the list by first name alphabetically? I have tried to do `Collections.sort` but it doesn't recognize `GraphUser`.

HELP!

**Get FB Friends and put them in List GraphUser, which is then passed to ArrayAdapter**

```
private List<GraphUser> fbFriends;

private void requestFacebookFriends(Session session) {
    Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
    friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            fbFriends = getResults(response);
            FriendsListAdapter adapter = new FriendsListAdapter(PickFriendActivity.this, R.layout.listview_row_friend, fbFriends);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    friendsRequest.executeAsync();
}

private Request createRequest(Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] requiredFields = new String[] {"id", "name", "picture"};
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

    Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
    parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
    request.setParameters(parameters);

    return request;
}

private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
    GraphMultiResult multiResult = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
    GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
    return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
}
```

**UPDATED w/ ANSWER**

```
private class FriendComparator implements Comparator<Friend> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Friend user1, Friend user2) {
            return user1.getFbName().compareTo(user2.getFbName());
        }
    }

Collections.sort(fbFriends, new FriendComparator());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Collection.sort that takes a comparator object, and define a comparator for GraphUsers that compares the names.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand how to do that. Can you give me an example? Haven't used `Collection.sort` before sorry!

Comment: Collection.sort has a version that takes a Comparator object.  Comparators can compare two values and return which one is less than the other (or if the two are equal).  You need to make a Comparator object for GraphUser.  Really it can just be a wrapper for the String comparator passing in the two names.

Comment: @TheNomad mind sharing how you achieved this? Any code example I can take a quick look at?

Comment: @JadeByfield I updated my question above to include the answer. Please note I made a custom `Friend` class because I didn't want to include all the extraneous info FB gave me.